# Fluid particles exploding for some reason

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I've tried multiple resolution, timesteps and viscosity settings to no avail, the fluid always explodes in the first frames. These results are with 90 divisions, 8 timesteps max and 6 min, 0,010 viscosity, diffusion base as 1 and exponent as 1 too, and I'm using APIC. Baking it also takes way too long, so I keep having to wait for it to bake for maybe hours to see that the results are still bad. Any help on this?

[image: Gif showing the best results I could manage, but the explosion is still there]

Comment: I've been experimenting with mantaflow for the last couple weeks, both with smoke and liquids. I find it is still not very stable and glitches like that happen a lot. I believe they tend to happen more often when you are using a force field of some kind (like wind or turbulence), so if you are, try removing it to see if the liquid still explodes.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know you could use force fields with a fluid simulation, so yeah.

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XD5vDQex" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XD5vDQex/)

Answer (score 1):

Go into the particle settings, click on physics and increase the mass of the particle.
[image]

When fluid particles collide they produce kinetic energy, by increasing the particle mass more energy would be required to create an explosion effect.